# Displaying an image from file in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

```java
public class Menu extends JFrame {
private static Frame frame;
private static Canvas canvas;
private int width;
private BufferedImage testImage;
private int height;
private Graphics g;
private static int canvasWidth = 0;
private static int canvasHeight = 0;
private static final int GAME_WIDTH = 400;
private static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 250;
private static int gameWidth = 0;
private static int gameHeight = 0;
public static void getBestSize() {
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        canvasWidth += GAME_WIDTH;
        canvasHeight += GAME_HEIGHT;
        if (canvasWidth > screenSize.width || canvasHeight > screenSize.height) {
        canvasWidth -= GAME_WIDTH;
        canvasHeight -= GAME_HEIGHT;
        done = true; 
    }
}
    int xDiff = screenSize.width - canvasWidth;
    int yDiff = screenSize.height - canvasHeight;
                                                                                                                            int factor = canvasWidth / GAME_WIDTH;
                                                                                                                            gameWidth = canvasWidth / factor + xDiff / factor;
    gameHeight = canvasHeight / factor + yDiff / factor;
    canvasWidth = gameWidth * factor;
    canvasHeight = gameHeight * factor;
}
public Menu (int w, int h) {
    getBestSize();
    height = h;
    width = w;
    frame = new Frame();
    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    frame.add(canvas);
    makeFullscreen();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            Menu.quit();
        }});
    startRendering();
}       
private static void startRendering() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = canvas.getGraphicsConfiguration();
            VolatileImage vImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(gameWidth, gameHeight);
            while (true) {
                if (vImage.validate(gc) == VolatileImage.IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE) {
                    vImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(gameWidth, gameHeight);
                }
                Graphics g = vImage.getGraphics();
                g.clearRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
                g.dispose();
                g = canvas.getGraphics();

                g.dispose();
                g = canvas.getGraphics();
            }
        }
    };          
    thread.start();
}
public static void quit() {
System.exit(0);
}
private static void makeFullscreen() {
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
        (frame).setUndecorated(true);
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    }
}
public void setUpMenu() {
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.setTitle("Masters");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    testImage = ImageLoader.loadImage("menu.png");
    g.drawImage (testImage, 20, 20, null);
    makeFullscreen();
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu m = new Menu(1920, 1080);
        m.setUpMenu();
    }

}
```

This is just a window that goes full-screen, but the problem is my testImage does not display on the screen. Any ideas? I put my image in the right place, so that should not be a problem.

```java
public class ImageLoader {
    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my 2nd main class, which just gets the images from my folder. I have watched some *youtube* guides on how to do it and followed every step (please note that I completely misunderstod these videos and mashed them together and am in no way saying these videos are bad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXmUp4ZTW2Q from this video i got the graphics from, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQEEsR559QQ&t=2s this video i have gotten the image on fullscreen from), but it didn't work. The code shows no errors, it just wont display images.

Comment: Honestly you wrote "watched some youtube guides". It definitely helps if you post the links to that videos. This is valuable research, you did: "followed every step". Now let us follow these steps too. Add the link/URL to the video (your research) and write down the steps you followed (what you tried). Then we can bring you back on track ️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote in your question...

> I have watched some youtube guides

Either those guides were bad or you misunderstood them.

You seem to be making things much more complicated than they need to be. If all you want to do is display an image in a full screen window, the below code is a minimal example of how to do that.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Menu implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;

    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Menu");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("menu.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(ico);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Menu());
    }
}
```

It appears to me that the written word is headed for extinction. Personally I prefer the written word to watching videos when it comes to learning but I guess that the *device screen* generation does not.

If you are willing to learn by reading, I recommend the tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). If you are willing to read a book, then I suggest one (or more) of the following (in no particular order):

1. [Core JFC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013090581X) (2nd edition) by Kim Topley
2. [Java Swing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596004087) (2nd edition) by James Elliott (and others)
3. [The Definitive Guide to Java Swing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594479) by John Zukowski

Comment: I must stress 3 things for good questions & answers (as seen here):
(1) __Written guides__ are multi-purpose: you can search (digitally or use a books' index) and copy-paste text-excerpts (at least point to a URL, page). Do provide a link, so everyone can follow!
(2) __Following some steps__ (from public texts/videos or private books): Do list the steps (in human language), so everyone can follow and share their understanding.
(3) __Code-only__ usually can not speak alone. It suffers explanation. The How-To-Do recipe can only be expressed in human language accompanying the code.